# HP Proliant ML110 G6 RAM Upgrade Issues

Tags: memory, hp

We have an HP Proliant ML110 G6 server running here at work which presently has only 8Gb RAM installed. The RAM presently in the system is Integral IN3T4GEZBIX or in other words PC3-10600 unbuffered, ECC, CL9, 1.5V stuff.

As we want to upgrade to 16Gb, we've just bought exactly the same RAM as is already installed however when we insert the new modules, the server complains on start-up that there is an error with the memory in the DIMM slots and still only reports 8Gb.

We've done a pretty comprehensive search of the web to try and figure out what the problem may be however all answers seem to relate to the type of RAM being installed in the system. We figured that buying the same type of RAM that already works must at least give us a fighting chance however this doesn't seem to be the case.

Please could anyone offer advice as to what we could try next?

Thanks in advance,
Kev

Comment: Can you try the new sticks in the same slots as the existing two? One of your new sticks could be bad.

Comment: New sticks have been tried in the same slots. In fact, we're running the new sticks on the server now in those slots, with the old sticks sat on the side waiting for inspiration and a bit of server-love.

Comment: OK, so that rules out bad sticks. Next up: bad slots. What happens when you try the old sticks in the spare (new) slots?

Comment: This is a good point and one route we've yet to try. Will post back the findings...

Comment: Yeah, the bad slots could be the case here. Would like to see, how you deal with that issue.

Answer (score 1):

For that model you need to use compatible DIMM module from HP. (& latest bios) (HP supported PC3-10600E UDIMM in 1, 2, or 4GB capacities)

HP List that for the G6:
4GB (256MB x 8) PC3-10600E, DIMM memory module **PartNumber: 501541-001**  (http://h20566.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=3984625&calledBy=Search_Result&docId=emr_na-c02281494&docLocale=en_US)

Strangely, Kingston memory search's tool does not list the G6, http://www.kingston.com/us/memory/system_specific/server, so please check to be sure it's really supported for the module you have.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Given that the RAM we've tried to install is identical to the working RAM inside the server, it should be supported and should just work? As far as the Integral datasheet for the RAM suggests, we're using 256MBx8, PC3-10600E DIMM modules.

Comment: If you read the question, the OP already has two modules which work, and has bought the exact same pair to expand the capacity. The HP list is not exclusive - I have personally used third-party modules in the past with no issues.

Comment: @CraigWatson Yes, but you miss my point, third part website does not offer an equivalent. HP is not the best for compatibility sometime, that's why I propose a bios update too in my first sentence.

Comment: Sure, but if the OP already has the exact same module kit in use, simply adding two more of the same model shouldn't require a new BIOS. Compatibility isn't an issue as the same model has worked before.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't download the latest BIOS as the server's warranty has expired. HP won't reveal the download link.

Comment: @CraigWatson It's not the same, it got handled by HP. You can verify all chip to be sure it's not modified ? If you theory is good, then why the upgrade make the server beep ?

Comment: @weblar83 Can you test with only the new two module ? That would rule out my idea if it still beep

Comment: See comments above. Server is currently running with the two new modules but in the same slots as the old modules.

Comment: @yagmoth555 see my comments on the question. Most RAM issues (IMHO) are down to bad sticks or slots. I've never, ever had a issue that has been down to compatibility, and I've been using off-HCL kit for a while.

Comment: @CraigWatson The new stick work alone in same slot I just seen, could be bad slots then.

Answer (score 0):

IN3T4GEZBIX is 4GB modules, have you bought 2 x 4GB additional Memory modules or single 8GB module? When you install memory, you will need to install them in a pair to corresponding memory sockets. For example, install 4GB in A1 socket and another 4GB in B1 socket.

just checked HP quickspecs and maximum it can take is 16GB ( 4x4GB). On you case, either memory modules are faulty or DIMMS itself. It could also be worth making sure memory modules are sit properly and tight as dust would have accumulated DIMMS. 
Would you please perform below tests:
Test 1: move working  (old) memory to new 2 x DIMMs, if it works, you know DIMMS are OK.
Test 2: Install just new Memory in OLD used DIMMS, if it doesn't work, you know it is issue with memory ifself. But if it does work, install old memory into new remaining DIMMs as you know it work on them in test 1.

Comment: Hi, we bought an additional 2x4Gb modules to match the 2x4Gb already installed.

Comment: Have you installed them in parallel in two DIMMS/sockets? if they are not installed in parallel sockets, it will give you error messages.

Comment: There are only 4 slots in total, all were filled

Comment: Hi, I have edited my answer and please perform test accordingly and you will find the culprit.

Comment: It isn't an issue with the memory, the memory works (see other posts). The only remaining possibility is the slots

Comment: In that case, as I mentioned in my answer. those DIMMs might have accumulated dust and preventing proper installation. try giving it a little clean, try re-installing memory few times that would also help clean connectors. if this doesn't fix, you won't be able to upgrade server memory as each DIMM can only take upto 4GB unfortunately.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your motherboard or CPU socket pins may be unhealthy.

I do recommend using HP RAM for this as well. While you may have identical part numbers, many times those memory lots can be sourced from different manufacturers. Certain combinations may not be compatible.

---

As far as obtaining firmware for your server, try harder.

[image]

See that "File name"? [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=CP016013.scexe&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

To verify it just switch in the **Installation instructions**

[image]

Where you can check the md5sum provided by HP, in this case `6adc72a3303ee49a0f2739738c157e42   CP016013.scexe`

Comment: Thanks for the tips on how to Google. I have, and both sources for the BIOS are unverifiable - how can I trust what is in that file is genuine?